# CSS-Sprites + D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, css-sprites

I'm trying to append HTML elements within a `<circle>` and then use CSS-Sprite to fill them, but so far I can't see them!

Here's what im doing:

```
 //Create the node in order to use the Force Layout
 var node = svg.selectAll(".container")
    .data(data)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[xVar]); }) //xAxis position
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[yVar]); }) //yAxis position
    .append("xhtml:i")
    .attr('class',  function(d) {
      return 'sprite '+ d['css-code'];
    });
```

And my css:

```
.sprite{
    position: absolute; 
    background:url(sprite.png) no-repeat;
}

.ad{background-position:0 -704px;}
.ae{background-position:0 -736px;}
.etc
```

They are being generated and I can see them on my browser inspector with the correct css atributes but they just won't appear.

How do I use CSS-Sprites with D3's Force Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the `<i>` elements directly within the SVG `<circle>` elements, which is not legal SVG markup. There are at least a couple of alternatives that you could use.

- Make the nodes `<g>` elements which would contain both the `<circle>` elements and a different element for the sprite.
- Insert the HTML sprites directly in the HTML container for the graph and absolutely position them to correspond with the node positions.

Comment: If I insert them directly in the HTML will they respond to the force layout? That's the only reason why I need them appended to those `<circle>`'s

Comment: I think you misunderstand how force layout works. It doesn't position the nodes for you. That's your job. And, at the same time you position the circles you can also position the sprites. See http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right direction @StephenThomas. I've finally made it work, check it out [here](https://www.comparacaodefundos.com/blog/como-ganhar-a-copa/#x-axis-menu) if you want!